# PHP: How to tell Eclipse/Netbeans that an object is of a certain class, to enable Intellisense

Tags: php, eclipse, class, netbeans, intellisense

I use Kohana 3.x as my Webapplication-Framework (which uses the MVC pattern) and use Propel as my ORM. Within my Controller I create an object that represents the profile that owns the current session:

```
$this->currentProfile = ProfileQuery::create()->findPK($profileId);
```

I pass the object to the views, that I use:

```
View::set_global('myProfile', $this->currentProfile); // c
```

Now I can use the object "myProfile" within my Views. But the problem is, that within this views, neither Netbeans nor Eclipse know the class of the object. So I cant use Intellisense anymore (which was one of the key-features for using Propel in the first place). So please help me: How can I tell Eclipse and/or Netbeans of which class my object "myProfile" is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Netbeans solution: put this at the beginning of your template: `/* @var $myProfile Profile */`

Or: type `vdoc` and press tab.

Comment: If passing as a argument to a function like I was, including this within your function (as opposed to the top of the document) worked for me.